# how to make the original view show

Tags: ios

I have 2 ViewController, A and B. Both of them inside a NavigationController. When I push A to B, I want B size only in center and stay in front of A, But the A behind should show the alpha = 1, but I can't do this. The A screen is black like this

[image]

Here is my code at B in ViewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
        height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
        self.navigationController?.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, width! - 200, height! - 200)
        title = ""
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }
```

All I want to set the view behind is show with alpha = 0.5. Not black like this. Mean the ViewController A is show instead of black screen, but of course we can not click anywhere in the view behind. Anyhelp would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to show ViewControllerA underneath ViewControllerB

In Interface Builder on ViewControllerB set its presentation mode to "Over Current Context":

[image]

NOTE: This only really works with the later version of iOS. I think iOS 7 and previous you will still get the black background.